# jQuery UI slider isn't changing width of .ui-slider-range when 'range' set to "min" or "max"

Tags: jquery-ui-slider

Version of jQuery UI: 1.10.4. The problem is mostly described in title. When range is set to `true` it is fine: `.ui-slider-range` gets inline style with width of 100% and this width is updated when you slide, but when it is "min" or "max" no style is attached and on slide the handle changes its `left` while nothing happens to `.ui-slider-range`.

Comment: Read the documentation properly. I don't think you understood the max and min property of jQuery UI Slider. This question makes no sense. That is why there is no response. Add a picture or sample code for more clarity.

Answer (score 2):

So well. I found out the problem myself. It was my bad, as I haven't noticed that if use `min` or `max` values of `range` property, you also have to use `value` (as a number) not `values` as an array as initial setting.